# Javascript - normalized vector only rotating in a range of 180 degrees

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, vector-graphics, rotational-matrices

I am attempting to create a small asteroids game in Javascript, and I've gotten it to the point where the ship draws on the screen and can fly around. However, whenever I try to rotate it by a certain amount, it can only rotate between +/- PI/2. I need it to cover more than just that range of 180 degrees, or else the ship can never turn around. I'm trying to do this from scratch using a custom 2D Vector class, and I've had a couple people look at it with no luck as to what to do.

Here's my vector code, or at least the constructor and rotation functions.

```
function Vec2D(x, y) {
    var self = this;
    var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
    this.x = x !== null ? Number(x) : 0;
    this.y = y !== null ? Number(y) : 0;
}
Vec2D.prototype.rotate = function (deg) {
    var theta = deg * (Math.PI / 180),
        xTemp = this.x;
    this.x = this.x * Math.cos(theta) - this.y * Math.sin(theta); 
    this.y = xTemp * Math.sin(theta) + this.y * Math.cos(theta);
    return this;
}
```

And here's the code for where my ship is trying to rotate.

```
function Ship(x_, y_, size_) {
    this.position = new Vec2D(x_, y_);
    this.velocity = new Vec2D(0, 0);
    this.forward = new Vec2D(0, 0);
    //some other things
    this.turningRight = false;
    this.turningLeft = false;
    this.turnAmt = 5;
    //some more things
}
Ship.prototype.update = function () {
   //other update code
   if (this.turningRight) {
        this.forward.rotate(this.turnAmt);
        console.log("right");
   }
   if (this.turningLeft) {
        this.forward.rotate(-1.0 * this.turnAmt);
        console.log("left");
   }
   //end of rotation code in update
}
```

I can reproduce more code if necessary, but this is all the relevant code as far as I can tell. I've tried console printing, I've tried messing with the rotation matrix, and I've even tried using only radians as opposed to converting it from degrees every time (which in all honesty I really should be doing anyway).

Any thoughts on my gross novice JavaScript?

Comment: Are you trying to rotate your ship around its own centerpoint?  are you trying to rotate your ship around some point in space (and is this point in space fixed)?

Comment: I'm rotating the forward (acceleration) vector, which is added to the velocity vector. the velocity vector's heading is what determines the ship's rotation. should I be rotating the velocity vector directly or is rotating the acceleration vector the right idea?

Comment: If you want to use vectors to do asteroids style ship movement: http://kindohm.com/blog/2013/05/24/coquette-javascript-game-spacehsips.html The github repository is here:  https://github.com/kindohm/space-janitor/tree/basic-spaceship/js  They use the sylvester.js vector helper lib: https://github.com/kindohm/space-janitor/tree/basic-spaceship/js